# javascript calculate total from dropdown and checkbox not updating to 0 when on another select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that calculate total based on dropdown boxes and check boxes , I have main drop down menu with

```
<select id="type" name="menu">
<option value="">Service Needed</option>
<option value="kite">Car Wash & Detailing</option>
<option value="user">Mechanic visit</option>
<option value="elect">Electrican visit</option>
<option value="tyre">Tyre Service</option>
<option value="bat">Battery Service</option>
</select>

SUB MENU


 <select  id="type2" name="buyername" class="form-control input-lg form-el calculate" >
 <option data-price="0" value="">-- Select --</option>
 <option data-price="100" value="kite1">Car Wash exterior</option>
 <option data-price="150" value="kite1">Car Wash In & Out</option>
 <option data-price="1000" value="kite2">Full Detailing</option>
 </select>
```

now when you select service like car wash & detailing then choose car wash exterior from sub menu the total price shown is 100, then after i click on another service like mechanic visit the price still on 100 , it should be 0 again as the price menu is deselected

here is the script

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
 $(function(){
 $("select.calculate").on("change", calc);
 $("input[type=checkbox].calculate").on("click", calc);

 function calc() {
 var basePrice = 0;
 newPrice = basePrice;
// You need to loop over, not only the selected option, but also the checked checboxes
 $("select.calculate option:selected,input[type=checkbox].calculate:checked").each(function (idx, el) {
  newPrice += parseInt($(el).data('price'), 10);
});

newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(2);
$("#item-price").html(newPrice);
}
});
 </script>
```

any idea how to fix this.??

Comment: `java` != `javascript`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eLL4bku3/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need a reset event handler on your main menu, something like this:

```
 $("#type").on("change", function() {
        $("select.calculate option").eq(0).prop('selected', true);
    calc();
 });
```

When you change your main menu (triggering a change event) this will reset your sub menu to the first option (`--select--`) and rerun your calc function, zeroing the output.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eLL4bku3/).

Comment: Working , Thanks delinear , but what if i have a second sub menu , moving from submenu 1 after getting total to submenu 2 will give the same problem.

Comment: moving from car wash & detailing then to the submenu "car wash exterior" will give total 100 , now moving direct to submenu battery service " battery rescue " will add battery rescue menu price to car wash exterior price